# Cannot connect Prisma with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, prisma

**schema.prisma**

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model employees {
  // This sets the id of the database. This parameter will be auto-generated by the MongoDB database
  Employee_id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  // Add the first name as a string
  Firstname String
  // Add the Surname as a string
  Surname String
  // Add the Email address as a string
  Email String
  // create a date field on when the data was added to MongoDB using the now() parameter
  Hired_on DateTime @default(now())
}
```

**.env**

```
DATABASE_URL="mongodb+srv://<username:<password>@cluster0.ds3t9sn.mongodb.net/post?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

**cmd**

```
D:\Prisma\post>npx prisma db push
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": MongoDB database "test" at "cluster0.jnuulkq.mongodb.net"
Error: MongoDB error
Kind: An error occurred during DNS resolution: proto error: io error: 通訊端操作嘗試連線到一個無法連線的網路。 (os error 10051), labels: {}
0: schema_core::commands::schema_push::Calculate `from`
         at schema-engine\core\src\commands\schema_push.rs:29
1: schema_core::state::SchemaPush
         at schema-engine\core\src\state.rs:436
```

I am getting difficulty trying to connect Prisma with MongoDB. I am wondering whether my `.env` has problems with the database name. The error shows that there is DNS error so anyone can provide suitable solutions to solve the problem?

Comment: `mongodb.net` does not exist, therefore you cannot reach it.

Comment: Any alternative solutions?

Comment: Double-check the cluster address you're using because, like I said, there is no mongodb.net. A `whois` request throws an error.

Comment: I checked clearly the cluster and when I watched the documentation online, I followed thoroughly and still throw out the current error

Answer (score 0):

`mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0.<server>.mongodb.net/dbName?retryWrites=true&w=majority`